# Interactive 3D object in Surface

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d, pixelsense

How to create a interactive 3D object in WPF? For example it can be a 3D Cube which can be rotated and with "tap" gesture for each side triggering different action.

Comment: You might want to clarify the tags; surface and silverlight are worlds apart

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the ViewPort3D class - it has a camera that you can rotate in 3d.  Just hook up a MouseDown event handler and modify the camera position.

http://www.kindohm.com/technical/wpf3dtutorial.htm

Comment: Surface doesn't have a mousedown - it has touch events. Same idea, though - but you need to figure out what to do when you have 30 touches dragging the same object in different directions ;-p

Comment: Oh duh, i guess there's no mouse!  Do the touch events come through the same mechanism as the Stylus (i.e. same as touch events in Windows 7)?

Comment: You can put a control(e.g. button) on each side of the cube as a texture and it will work as if you clicked on it, then you can simply implement ClickButton events.

Answer (score 1):

Interactive 3D **effects** are certainly doable in WPF/Surface, although it'll take a bit of work. For example, have a look at the [stuff here](http://drdave.co.uk/blog/post/Surface-Physics-Demo-Part-3.aspx), especially the rolling globe about 1:50 into the first picture. The implementation shown is Surface, but that is largely WPF with some different input mechanisms... Unfortunately, he doesn't show the code...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [codeplex.com/3DTools](http://codeplex.com/3DTools). Wrap your `ViewPort3D` into `Interactive3DDecorator`.